# Find a user in Azure Active Directory based on any of their email addresses

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

I needed to find a user based on their email address (to which they had received a license) and then connect that back to their primary identity for our internal billig.

In AD there are 2 fields that hold the emails:

- `email`
- `proxyAddresses.*`

How can I find the actual user's identity based on any 1 of their email addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding a user by their primary email address is quite simple:

```
# user based on primary email
& az ad user list --query "[?mail=='$email'].userPrincipalName"
```

Finding a user based on an email alias is a bit harder. In our case these are all stored in the `proxyAddresses` field in their user profile and the values are prefixed with `smtp:`. To find them use:

```
# user based on alias
& az ad user list --filter "proxyAddresses/any(p:p eq 'SMTP:$email')" --query "[].userPrincipalName"
```

Comment: why not make the API call instead of using the CLI?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I could... But then I need to correctly implement a whole bunch of other stuff, and still need to figure out the correct API call... I wouldn't mind if you'd add a second answer with an alternative way to do this.

Comment: It would require to install either the Az or the Microsoft.Graph modules, you could make an API call directly but getting the token is not as straight forward if you want to go vanilla

Answer (score 1):

- Using [`Microsoft.Graph`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview):

```bash
# Installed through the Gallery (one time only):
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph -Scope CurrentUser

Connect-MgGraph

# query for `mail`
Get-MgUser -Filter "mail eq '$email'"
# query for `proxyAddresses`
Get-MgUser -Filter "proxyAddresses/any(p:p eq 'SMTP:$email')"
```

- Using [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-10.4.1):

```bash
# Installed through the Gallery (one time only):
Install-Module Az -Scope CurrentUser

Connect-AzAccount

# query for `mail`
Get-AzADUser -Filter "mail eq '$email'"
# query for `proxyAddresses`
Get-AzADUser -Filter "proxyAddresses/any(p:p eq 'SMTP:$email')"
```

If you want to go full vanilla and query the [user API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0) directly you will need an application with one of these [Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) then the code to request a token and query the API would be (**notice variables that should be pre-populated: `$appid`, `$secret`, `$tenantId`, `$email`**):

```bash
# get token
$params = @{
    Uri    = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    Method = 'POST'
    Body   = @{
        Grant_Type    = 'client_credentials'
        Scope         = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
        Client_Id     = $appid
        Client_Secret = $secret
    }
}
$token = Invoke-RestMethod @params

$uri = [System.UriBuilder]::new('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users')

# query for `mail`
$uri.Query = "`$filter=mail eq '$email'"

$request = @{
    Uri     = $uri.ToString()
    Headers = @{
        Authorization = $token.token_type + ' ' + $token.access_token
    }
}
(Invoke-RestMethod @request).value

# query for `proxyAddresses`
$uri.Query = "`$filter=proxyAddresses/any(p:p eq 'SMTP:$email')"

$request = @{
    Uri     = $uri.ToString()
    Headers = @{
        Authorization = $token.token_type + ' ' + $token.access_token
    }
}
(Invoke-RestMethod @request).value
```