# How can i get a token from Microsodt.Graph using powershell?

Tags: powershell, msal

I am trying to get a token from Microsoft.Graph using Powershell. I am using the following:

```
 $clientId = <clientid>
 $scopes = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
 $tenantId = <tenantid>
 $token = Get-MsalToken -ClientId $clientId -TenantId $tenantId -Scopes $scopes
 $accessToken = $token.AccessToken
```

But when i run this i get an error :

```
 The term 'Get-MsalToken' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function
```

Any ideas on how i can make this work or Get a token any other way ?

Comment: Well, `Get-MsalToken` is from MSAL.PS so you need to `Install-Module MSAL.PS` to use it :) If you can't install modules, you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77614905/15339544) it shows how to get a token without any modules.

Comment: Yes i have installed the module , but it gives the same error

Comment: Where are you running this code? You have probably installed it for a different runtime

Comment: I am running the code from Powershell run locally on a Windows 11 machine . Powershell is run as administrator

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you need to install the MSAL.PS module to use `Get-MsalToken`

```
Install-Module msal.ps
```

Comment: doesnt work , gives same error. I have also installed Microsoft.Graph ?

Answer (score 0):

this is what u need:

```
$clientId = #enter clientid here
$secret = #enter secret here
$tenantId = #enter tenantid here

$body = {
    Grant_Type = 'client_credentials'
    Scope = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/default.'
    Client_Id = $clientId
    Client_Secret = $secret
}

$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Body $body -uri "https//login.microsoft.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
```

In regards to the error message u get:

The term 'Get-MsalToken' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function

That indicates that the module can't be found. So specify the path to the module - e.g. import-module C:\mymodule\mymodule.ps1

But u don't need it anyways...